# PYSPARK // drop rows like df_new = df_old.iloc[::nth, :]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm working with pyspark data frames (pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame).
The data frame consists of ~20.000 rows and I want to extract only 1 in 20 rows to a new data frame, which then has ~1.000 rows.

In python/pandas, this can be easily done by `df_new = df_old.iloc[::20, :]` .
How can this be done in pyspark?

Comment: many options - you could use `limit`, `head`, `take`, create row_numbers and filter, are a few -- [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/dataframe.html)

Comment: I don't know what the solution might look like, only know pandas

Comment: You can use sample also if that's what you are trying to do